# playframework websocket closing in production env

Tags: playframework, websocket

Using playframework 2.5.6, java, I've established a websocket over http (from a react web client).  In dev, the connection will stay open indefinitely but will close after about 50 seconds in production (built with `./activator universal:packageZipTarball`).

I've tried setting `play.server.http.idleTimeout` to various values ("120 seconds", null, -1), but it doesn't seem that this is used on websocket connections.

Is there another way to configure this or am I missing something else?

I'm using streams and connecting the websocket via actors following [this example](https://github.com/playframework/play-websocket-java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the TCP keepAlive is off in prod env. A common way to keep the ws connection open is to ping your server every x seconds.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing.  Easy enough to do a setTimeout and send a ping message. Thanks!